# reading in chunks from a big file using java

Tags: java, file, file-io, io, randomaccessfile

I have a big file with 10K entities (entity per row)

I want to read it in chunks of 1K entities to List.

I have tried:

```
public List<String> getNextRequestsChunk() {
    List<String> requests = new ArrayList<>();
    try {

        randomAccessFile.seek(currentSeekPosition);

        String line = null;
        while ((requests.size() < chunkSize) && (line = randomAccessFile.readLine()) != null)
        {
            currentSeekPosition += line.length();
            requests.add(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }

    return requests;
}
```

I have this file:

```
11
22
33
..
100100
```

and when i re-run this method for chunk#2 it doesn't give me the expected string `33` but string `2`

(`chunkSize` is 2 lines, `currentSeekPosition` = 4)

how can i fix this?

Comment: what it gives you if not line 10?

Comment: make sure currentSeekPosition is not reset somewhere outside

Comment: I think you need to add: currentSeekPosition += line.length() + 1;

Comment: Why are you even messing around with seek()? Just read the data and let the file pointer advance automatically.

Comment: i'll try. i guess you're right

Answer (score 1):

Add  `currentSeekPosition = randomAccessFile.getFilePointer();`  after `while` loop

```
public List<String> getNextRequestsChunk() {
    List<String> requests = new ArrayList<>();
    try {

        randomAccessFile.seek(currentSeekPosition);

        String line = null;
        while ((requests.size() < chunkSize) && (line = randomAccessFile.readLine()) != null)
        {
            // currentSeekPosition += line.length()+1; 
            requests.add(line);
        }
       // add this 
       currentSeekPosition = randomAccessFile.getFilePointer();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }

    return requests;
}
```

Your problem was that `readLine` method doesn't count the new line character `\n`.